# Let $A = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ . Using elementary matrices, determine $A^n$ for any natural number $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $$A =\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Using what you know about elementary matrices, determine $A^n$
>   for any natural number $n$.

I am trying to solve the above question but do not understand what it's asking for. What does $A^n$ mean in terms of matrices?

Comment: $A^n$ is not defined for $A$ the way you have written it.  Do you mean $A = \pmatrix {1&0\\1&1}.$  $A^n$ means the same thing for matrices as it does for real numbers.  Multiply $A$ by itself $n$ times.  Start with the sequence, $A, AA, AAA$ look for a pattern, and try to prove what will come next.

Comment: Yes I meant it by that.

Comment: "*Use what you know about elementary matrices*"  Is $A$ an elementary matrix?  What operation does it describe?  If you repeat that operation multiple times on itself, what happens?  (*$A$ is an elementary matrix... it describes adding* ____ *to* _____ )

Comment: $$A^n = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\n&1\end{pmatrix}$$ Pretty easy to show via induction.

Answer (score 6):

$A^n$ means multiplying $  A$ $n$ times by itself, just as normal power with natural numbers. The matrix you have there is the elementary operation of adding the first row to second one. So:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ {c+a} & {d+b} \end{bmatrix}$$

This means:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ n & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ n+1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then:
$$A^n=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ n & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This doesn’t follow the additional instruction in the problem statement: “Using what you know about elementary matrices...”

Answer (score 0):

Take your matrix $A$ and using what you know about matrix multiplication, multiply it by an arbitrary matrix, call it $B$.
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}\to A\cdot B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & b \\
 a+c & b+d \end{pmatrix}
$$
You see that your matrix leaves the first row unchanged and each element in the bottom row is what it was before plus the entry above it. So you can see if you multiply $A$ by $A$, $n$ times the top row must remain $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The first entry in the bottom row will be $1+1(n-1)=n$ and the remaining entry will be $1+0(n-1)=1$ (the $n-1$ is because following my example $B=A^{n-1}\to A^n=A\cdot A^{n-1}$).

So you have
$$
A^n=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\n&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Ah, just saw @Villa did the same thing as I did while I was writing. I'll leave it here anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
      p(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda-1)^2.
$$

Therefore $(A-I)^2=0$. It follows that $(A-I)^k=0$ for all $k\ge 2$ and, hence,
\begin{align}
     A^n &= (I+(A-I))^n \\
         &=I+n(A-I) \\
         &=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ n & 1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}